Botpress Choices & Userquery

I'm currently working on building a bot that can take queries directly from choices or the user's input. However, I'm facing some challenges in achieving this. Specifically, when using choice in flow, the bot fails to detect if the user wants to enter a custom query instead of using the buttons.
I'm currently using v12.botpress.com and would appreciate any help or guidance.

